# Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $3^n+81$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $3^n+81$ is a perfect square.

**My solution**:

$3^n=a^2-81 \Rightarrow 3^n=(a-9)(a+9)$

$gcd(a-9,a+9) \mid 18$

because $a+9>a-9$ then $a-9$ can be $1,3,9$that only $a=9$ is the answer so we have only one solution.I just wanted to verify my answer is it right?

Comment: What about $n=5$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen for $a=9$ we get $n=5$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr but then we can go up and have more solutions for $a-9$.I mean answers like $27,81,/dots$

Comment: we can only get perfect square if 3 is raised to the power $4k+1$ or $4k+2$ we get $k=1$ for $4k+1$ now check for $4k+2$ if it does not give any solution then $n=5$ is the only one. here $k$ is whole number.

Comment: You state that $a-9$ can be $1$, $3$, or $9$.  These options lead to $a=10$, $a=12$, and $a=18$.  None of these is $a=9$.  Of these options, only $a=18$ works (not $a=9$).  Note that $9$ and $27$ are the *only* powers of $3$ which differ by $18$ (which is needed for the product to work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get $3^n = (a-9)(a+9)$ in the question.  But the only factors of $3^n$ are other powers of $3$, so you need $a-9$ and $a+9$ to both be powers of $3$. The only powers of three differing by $18$ are $9$ and $27$.  So $a = 18$, and the only solution is $18^2  = 3^5 + 81$.